# MVC5 - How do I define deserialization behavior for action parameter type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

```
    public class LogsController : Controller
    {
        public async Task<ActionResult> User(string id, int? page)
        {
            return await User(id, (Page)page);
        }

        private async Task<ActionResult> User(string id, Page page)
        {
            var data = await Repo.GetData(id, page, 10);
            var model = new UserLogs
            {
                User = id,
                Events = data,
                Pager = new PagerInput(page, 10, data.TotalCount)
            };

            return View("UserGrid", model);
        }
    }
```

My Page class provides useful functionality such as making sure the page is never less than 1, ect. However, if my public action takes Page as a parameter, it is always null, no matter the value in the form or querystring, even though I have defined implicit casts to and from int.

Is there anyway I can tell the MVC how to deserialize a Page type? Such a providing some sort of method/ctor to convert from string?

I would like to define it on the actual Page type since I will be using it in multiple controllers/actions.

I would be nice to not need the double action definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This custom model binder allows you to define deserialization behavior of any type by simply defining a constructor with a string parameter:

```
public class CustomModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    static Assembly _assembly = typeof(CustomModelBinder).Assembly;
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {   
        if (_assembly.Equals(bindingContext.ModelType.Assembly))
        {
            var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
            var ctor = bindingContext.ModelType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(string) });
            if (ctor != null && value != null)
                return ctor.Invoke(new object[] { value.AttemptedValue });
        }
        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

And register it...

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new CustomModelBinder();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You must create your own model binder.

Example for Guid:

```
public class GuidModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(
            ControllerContext controllerContext,
            ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(Guid) ||
            bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(Guid?))
        {
            Guid result;

            var valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

            if (valueResult.AttemptedValue == null &&
                    bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(Guid))
                return Guid.Empty;

            if (valueResult.AttemptedValue == null &&
                    bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(Guid?))
                return null;

            if (Guid.TryParse(valueResult.AttemptedValue, out result))
                return result;
        }

        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

After create binding config class:

```
public class BindingConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBinders(ModelBinderDictionary binders)
    {
        binders.Add(typeof(Guid), new GuidModelBinder());
        binders.Add(typeof(Guid?), new GuidModelBinder());
    }
}
```

At last call RegisterBinders from Application_Start:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    BindingConfig.RegisterBinders(ModelBinders.Binders);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this got me started on a more general solution.